# Create readonly user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, permissions, users, role

Using `pg 13.4`, created a **readonly** user `reader` for database `abc`, via:

```
CREATE ROLE reader WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'psssswwwd' 
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE abc TO reader;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO reader;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO reader;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO reader;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO reader;
```

But the user can still create table, then insert & drop that table.
I want the user unable to do any change to any of the databases in pg, and can only connect & read database `abc`.

I've checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332588/read-only-user-able-to-create-table,
and tried: `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM reader;`
but it can still create table.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REVOKE` statement you ran revoked a privilege that was never granted, so it does nothing.

If you have a look at the permissions, you will see that schema `public` has `CREATE` granted to `PUBLIC` (that is, everybody), so that's what you will have to revoke:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

Then you have to grant `CREATE` to the role that is supposed to create objects in that schema.

Comment: Ok, I see, so it will effect other user / role .. I'd better not do that ...

Comment: Wish pg can provide a simple command to create a read only user, for a given database, without these messy permission details.

Comment: [Your wish is granted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html) in v14 with `pg_real_all_data`.

Comment: Oh hooooooooooo, btw, you mean `pg_read_all_data`.

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction.